# SQL Joining tables to get other tables data

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume the following table:

```
-- Register
regid       descr               mainid      subid
  1         Registration #1     1           1
  2         Registration #2     2           3
  3         Registration #3     1           4
  4         Registration #4     2           2

-- MainCat
mainid      descr
  1         MainCat.1
  2         MainCat.2

-- SubCat
subid       descr
  1         SubCat.1
  2         SubCat.2
  3         SubCat.3
  4         SubCat.4
```

Howto get a result like this:

```
- Description: -     - MainCat -    - SubCat -
 Registration #1      MainCat.1      SubCat.1
 Registration #2      MainCat.2      SubCat.3
 Registration #3      MainCat.1      SubCat.4
 Registration #4      MainCat.2      SubCat.2
```

I tried a `left join` like

```
SELECT 
    Register.*,
    MainCat.descr AS MainCat,
    SubCat.descr AS SubCat
FROM
    Register
LEFT JOIN 
    MainCat ON
    Register.mainid = MainCat.mainid
LEFT JOIN
    SubCat ON
    Register.subid = SubCat.subid
WHERE
    Register.descr LIKE 'Registration%'
```

But somehow, it returns multiple of the same Register-records, with the wrong MainCat-descriptions. I'm feeling really dumb now :P

*Note: All the id's and descriptions of the categories (main and sub) are 100% unique. Also this is a simplified database of the original, but it has the same purpose.*

**So my questions are:**

- Did i correctly wrote my SQL?
- If yes: What could be the problem of the strange (duplicate) results
- If no: What is the right way to achieve this

P.S. `DISTINCT` does'nt work because its returning (wrong) different `MainCat.descr` and so there not 100% duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data in your sample this query based on inner join should show the excpeted result

```
       SELECT 
        Register.*,
        MainCat.descr AS MainCat,
        SubCat.descr AS SubCat
    FROM Register
    INNER JOIN  MainCat ON  Register.mainid = MainCat.mainid
    INNER JOIN  SubCat ON   Register.subid = SubCat.subid
    WHERE  Register.descr LIKE 'Registration%'
```

Left join is useful when not all the related column contain valid data .. in your case you have correct realtion between the 3 tables so you should use inner join

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna give it a try

Answer (score 1):

The only thing missing from your query is the `FROM` clause. When I add that in, it works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41450/1/0

Comment: You are right, forgot that one in the example in my question, but its there in the original query. +1 for well spotted and the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Select DISTINCT and that should give you unique rows your left joins are correct

Comment: I know, but even with `DISTINCT` i'm getting duplicate values, because it's returning the wrong `MainCat.descr` values. So it's not entirely the same and thus not a real duplicate. For `DISTINCT` the results must be exactly the same, what is not the case

Comment: SELECT all the data your requesting as Distinct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    R.descr  AS Description,
    MC.descr AS MainCat,
    SB.descr AS SubCat
FROM
    Register AS R
LEFT JOIN
    MainCat MC ON
    R.mainid = MC.mainid
LEFT JOIN
    SubCat SC ON
    R.subid = SC.subid
```

Comment: Is'nt this doing the exact same as my SQL, except for the extra aliases?

Comment: @RamonBakker It excludes the fields: redid, mainid, subid

Comment: @RamonBakker I think it's not necessary this: WHERE
    Register.descr LIKE 'Registration%'

Comment: It's just for the example. My real query looks a little different. The example in the question is just to check if i'm using the right technique